# Understanding Series Notation

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I'm trying to test the convergence of the series below, however, I'm unsure on what the $$9 \cdot 18\cdot27\cdot...\cdot(9n)$$ part of the series means and moreover how to apply a convergence test to the series.

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{9 \cdot 18\cdot27\cdot...\cdot(9n)}{n!}$$

I'm looking for some guidance on how to interpret the notation of the numerator of the series.

Comment: Should both occurrences of "$8$" be "$18$"?

Comment: It looks like a misprint for $9\cdot18\cdot27\cdots$, going up in nines.

Comment: Correct sorry I will edit

Answer (score 1):

If you are confused about the notation, the case $n=4$ is $9 \cdot 18 \cdot 27 \cdot 36$, and the case $n=5$ is $9 \cdot 18 \cdot 27 \cdot 36 \cdot 45$. In general it is the product of the first $n$ multiples of $9$.

---

Hint: $$9 \cdot 18 \cdot 27 \cdots (9n) = (9 \cdot 1) (9 \cdot 2) (9\cdot 3) \cdots (9 n) = 9^n \cdot n!$$

Comment: Thank you! Just the guidance I needed.

Comment: Can you apply the same methodology to something like 5⋅8⋅11⋅...⋅(3n+2) ?

Comment: @JohnDews If you want to show a series with that product diverges, then you can lower bound it by $3 \cdot 6 \cdot 9 \cdots (3n)$.